What's the idea behind managing a secret in a key vault via Terraform?
There is the possibility of managing a secret in a key vault via Terraform:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_secret
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  name         = "secret-sauce"
  value        = "szechuan"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

However then the secret szechuan would need to be commited to Git, and I was wondering what's the idea or use case behind using this Terraform resource? Should it for example be stored in a variable, but then from where would the value for the variable come from (without committing it to Git)?

That seems like a bad example like you said. Instead of that, you could use Hashicorp's Random provider and random_password resource to generate the secret and then output the vault id so that you can use it to reference the secret using the secret name/id. This way you avoid having actual secrets as plain text in your configuration code directly or using a variable.
From the documentation: "...the result is treated as sensitive and, thus, not displayed in console output."
Notice that secret generated this way should be redacted from the run output.
Marking variables as sensitive also works, but it would mean that you have to accept managing your secrets in your configuration code which makes sharing and managing those secrets a bit of a hassle.
There is more serious problem with sensitive values/secrets and Terraform, which is that the State file will store all values, sensitives too, as plain text.

What if the secret cannot be generated by myself, but is given to me because it's used to access e.g. a database managed by another team? Then it probably doesn't make sense to manage this secret via Terraform right? Should I then just create the key vault via Terraform, and then manually upload the secret to the key vault?

The passwords that I put in the vault are initially set as secret parameter to the azure pipeline that starts the terraform script (and passes the parameters).
Also I store a storage key that is generated at terraform runtime - and therefore not present in code.
